# Call Mapper.Map inside a custom type converter

Tags: c#, automapper

I know this question has been asked once 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883412/automapper-call-mapper-map-inside-a-custom-type-converter) but there wasn't necessary to call Automapper.Map() method inside custom type convertor. So what if I have this type of structure:

```
class MyType
{
    public double ValueToBeComputed1 { get; set; }

    public double ValueToBeComputed2 { get; set; }
}

class ComplexType
{
    public double ValueToBeComputed { get; set; }
    public MyType MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

For all the values to be computed I need to make different calculus  so I will have a custom type convertor for Complex type to let's say OtherType. My question is if I will be able to call Mapper.Map() for the property MyProperty inside that custom converter?

Comment: What happened when you tried calling it?

Comment: I did not called it yet, I just wanted to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I faced the outdated documentation for Automapper custom type converter, where the ITypeConverter interface has been changed, and I found the answer here:
[ITypeConverter interface has been changed in AutoMapper 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168856/itypeconverter-interface-has-been-changed-in-automapper-2-0) , I was able to make a working prototype which produces converted types as follows:

```
public class ComplexTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<ComplexSourceType, ComplexDestinationType>
{
    public ComplexDestinationType Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var source = (ComplexSourceType)context.SourceValue;

        return new ComplexDestinationType
        {
            MyProperty = Mapper.Map<SourceType, DestinationType>(source.MyProperty),
            ValueComputed = source.ValueToBeComputed + 10
        };
    }
}

public class TypeConverter : ITypeConverter<SourceType, DestinationType>
{
    public DestinationType Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var source= (SourceType)context.SourceValue;
        return new DestinationType
        {
            ValueComputed1 = source.ValueToBeComputed1 + 10,
            ValueComputed2 = source.ValueToBeComputed2 + 10
        };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<ComplexSourceType, ComplexDestinationType>().ConvertUsing(new ComplexTypeConverter());
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>().ConvertUsing(new TypeConverter());
        });

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        ComplexSourceType source = new ComplexSourceType
        {
            MyProperty = new SourceType
            {
                ValueToBeComputed1 = 1,
                ValueToBeComputed2 = 1
            },
            ValueToBeComputed = 1
        };
        var dest = Mapper.Map<ComplexSourceType, ComplexDestinationType>(source);
    }
}
```

The dest object holds the modified data with 11 on each property

Comment: I think the interface changed again. `Mapper` is not initialized for me.

Comment: @ahong you are right, from the day when this answer was written, the AutoMapper API was changed. I think  this answer was written for version 4.2.1 of AutoMapper and now it was released the version 9.0.0. which I assume you use. Depending on what you need to do, I encourage you to describe it in a comment under this question or open another one.

Comment: Late reply, but I just faced the same issue. You can now use `context.Mapper` to get the runtime mapper which should be initialized.